# Why get the connection that has been closed, resulting in "holder is null" error

Tags: java, spring-transactions, druid

This is the nesting problem, please help to analyze the reasons

Overall code structure description：

TransactionA in some of the DB operation, and then open the transactionB. TransactionA commit time to trigger a custom trigger, the trigger in the open transactionC (PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW)

[image]

The error process is like this:
The first run is correct no error, the second run time to get to a closed-connection，Test code is like this：

```
@Test
public void testNotify() {

    ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    while (true) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              //The following mainCode...

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Error stack：

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: connection holder is null
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.checkStateInternal(DruidPooledConnection.java:1122) ~[druid-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.checkState(DruidPooledConnection.java:1113) ~[druid-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.prepareStatement(DruidPooledConnection.java:318) ~[druid-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.instantiateStatement(PreparedStatementHandler.java:75) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.prepare(BaseStatementHandler.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.prepare(RoutingStatementHandler.java:57) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:73) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:59) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor132.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at com.youzan.pay.assetcenter.dal.monitor.SqlMonitorManager.intercept(SqlMonitorManager.java:53) ~[assetcenter.dal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:60) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:66) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor140.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358) ~[mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
```

Main code：

```
    //Open a local transaction PROPAGATION_REQUIRED
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {

                AcquireOrder acquireOrder = acquireOrderRepository.active(payResult.getAcquireNo());

                // Do some set...
                    acquireOrderRepository.reStore(acquireOrder);
                }

                 //1. Look at the following
                    transactionActivityService.start("assetcenter", "", new HashMap<>());

                    //... Some of the code to construct command

                    //2.Look at the following
                    transactionActivityService.enrollAction(SETTLEMENT_TOPIC,
                        JSONObject.toJSONString(settleCommand));

                    //3.Look at the following
                    transactionActivityService.enrollAction(CHARGE_TOPIC, JSONObject.toJSONString(payCommand));
                }

                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        });
```

1 Detailed code：

```
try {
            TransactionActivityRecord activity = requiredTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                transactionActivityStore.addTransactionActivity(activityRecord);
            }
        });
            TransactionActivityContextHolder.setCurrent(activity);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            TransactionActivityContextHolder.clear();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (TransactionActivityContextHolder.isActive()) {

                //The registration of synchronizer
                TransactionSynchronization synchronization = new FinalizeTransactionSynchronization(transactionActivityManager);
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(synchronization);
            }
        }
```

2、3 Detailed code：

```
requiredTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                transactionActivityStore.addTransactionAction(actionRecord);
            }
        });
```

3 The synchronization code(Problem code)：

```
public void afterCompletion(int status) {

        boolean actionRes = doSubmitActions(actions);

//This code raises questions.
        if(actionRes && activity.getState() == TransactionState.INIT) {
            transactionActivityStore.updateTransactionActivityState(activity.getTxId(),TransactionState.PREPARE);
        }

    }


/**
     * 执行事务参与者的提交
     * @param actions
     * @return
     */
    private boolean doSubmitActions(List<TransactionActionRecord> actions) {
        AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        if(actions != null && !actions.isEmpty()) {
            actions.stream().filter(action -> action.getState() == TransactionState.INIT).forEach(action -> {
                boolean res = dtsTransactionActionProducer
                        .push(action.getActionName(), JSON.toJSONString(action.getContext()));
                if (res) {
//Open a local transaction PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
                    requiresNewTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

                        @Override protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                            transactionActivityStore
                                    .updateTransactionActionState(action.getActionId(), TransactionState.PREPARE);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    log.warn("submit transaction-action failure topic:{},context:{}", action.getActionName(),
                            action.getContext());
                    result.compareAndSet(true,false);
                }
            });
        }
        return result.get();
    }
```

3 The synchronization code(Correct code)：

```
public void afterCompletion(int status) {

        boolean actionRes = doSubmitActions(actions);

//Put the following code in the doSubmitActions method in the requiresNewTransactionTemplate execution
        if(actionRes && activity.getState() == TransactionState.INIT) {
            transactionActivityStore.updateTransactionActivityState(activity.getTxId(),TransactionState.PREPARE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your diagram is wrong. The circle is not running inside transaction A, it is running *after* transaction A has completed (it is called `afterCompletion`, right?). So left code is trying to do "update db code" when there is no transaction context, exemplified by the fact that the "connection holder" is empty (`null`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the picture. The error process is like this:
The first run is correct no error, the second run time to get to a closed-connection, I added the test code.Why the second execution will get a connection that has been closed.

Comment: If you do not use the PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW will be before the connection can not be released, just be closed, resulting in the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW will be before the connection can not be released, just be closed, resulting in the problem

```
/**
     * Invoked after transaction commit. Can perform further operations right
     * <i>after</i> the main transaction has <i>successfully</i> committed.
     * <p>Can e.g. commit further operations that are supposed to follow on a successful
     * commit of the main transaction, like confirmation messages or emails.
     * <p><b>NOTE:</b> The transaction will have been committed already, but the
     * transactional resources might still be active and accessible. As a consequence,
     * any data access code triggered at this point will still "participate" in the
     * original transaction, allowing to perform some cleanup (with no commit following
     * anymore!), unless it explicitly declares that it needs to run in a separate
     * transaction. Hence: <b>Use {@code PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW} for any
     * transactional operation that is called from here.</b>
     * @throws RuntimeException in case of errors; will be <b>propagated to the caller</b>
     * (note: do not throw TransactionException subclasses here!)
     */
    void afterCommit();
```